# socket_read('wss://host'') returns an encrypted buffer that I can't decrypt

Tags: php, sockets, encryption, encoding

I'm trying to make a simple socket with PHP. So far, the socket begins to accept the request from the client, but the buffer I receive from the client is encrypted,

Here is my PHP, which is run on the server with `$ php file.php`:

```
$user_socks = array(0 => false);

$socket = socket_create_listen(8080);
socket_set_nonblock($socket);

while(true){
    $new_conn = socket_accept($socket);

    if(!$new_conn && !$user_socks[0])
        continue;

    if($new_conn && !$user_socks[0])
        $user_socks[0] = $new_conn;

    $buffer = socket_read($user_socks[0], 2048);
        var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($buffer, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8'));
}
```

I'm simply running this line of JS in the Firebug console to try connecting to the script:

```
var test = new WebSocket('wss://192.168.2.253:8080');
```

Does anybody know how I can decrypt this text?

Comment: your socket class is fine. test it out by telnetting to it - maybe the websocket is sending some binary protocol data or some such

Comment: @pala_ That definitely worked. After a quick test, it's the encryption from `wss://` that's  making my text unreadable. Any clue how to decrypt the buffer? I'm going to update my question.

Comment: maybe use something like this: https://www.stunnel.org/index.html. accepting ssl/tls is probably a wheel you dont need to reinvent

Comment: @pala_ Thanks for the suggestion. I'll do some testing and see if I can come up with something that works.

Comment: @pala_ I found a solution that worked for me involving `stunnel` with Apache's mod_proxy and friends. Just wanted to say thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I figured out how to get this to work. The solution turned out to be using `stunnel` as a daemon to provide encryption for the web socket.

Here are all of the extra pieces that were necessary in order to get this to work:

Apache VHost config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <IfDefine PROXY>
        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyPass "/wss/" "wss://127.0.0.1:4430"
        ProxyPassReverse "/wss/" "wss://127.0.0.1:4430"
    </IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>
```

Stunnel config

```
cert = /path_to_key.pem
key = /path_to_key.pem

[wss]
accept = 4430
connect = 8080
```

Then connect to the encrypted web socket with the following command

```
var test = new WebSocket('wss://hostname.tld/wss');
```